How to use mongodb Aggregation.addFields() reduce?
I want to convert the following code into spring data mongodb code.
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$children",
          initialValue: {
            level: -1,
            presentChild: [],
            prevChild: []
          },
          in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I tried the following:
val agg = newAggregation(
    Aggregation.addFields()
        .addField("children")
        .withValueOf(
            ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("children").withInitialValue(
                mapOf(
                    "level" to -1,
                    "presentChild" to emptyList<Any>(),
                    "prevChild" to emptyList<Any>()
                )
            )
        ).build()
)

output:
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      children: {
        val$initialValue: {
          level: -1,
          presentChild: [],
          prevChild: []
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

This is not the expected result.
I searched the web but found nothing.
what should I do?

This question is similar to: How do I write mongo aggregation reduce query in Spring?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ray The question you mentioned has not been resolved and is out of date for a long time.

$reduce(https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) needs in expression, which is missing in your query.

@Noel I asked for spring data mongodb code.

And, i asked for a "minimal, workable example". How do i run and test my answer if the code in the question is incomplete?

@Noel you just set logging.level.org.mongodb.driver.protocol: trace then you can test it, and the console will print the request sent to the mongodb server. Just focus on the converted mongodb query being correct, so I think this is the minimal example. If you insist, the full code is here.

"This is not the expected result." Please edit your question to include an example of what your expected result would be. See [mcve] for more information.

@TylerH 1. This question has been solved. 2. expected result is the first paragraph of json code.

@SageJustus That the question has been answered is irrelevant to the concern I raised. As for the first paragraph of JSON, that looks like the data you are starting with. If it is instead the desired result, then your question is missing the input data and still is missing an MCVE.

@TylerH The first code is the desired result, The second paragraph shows the faulty code and the third paragraph shows the output after the code is run. I don't quite understand what else is missing?

Both your query and Java code is missing in expression. It should look something like this.
Aggregation.addFields().addField("children")
    .withValueOf(
        ArrayOperators.Reduce.arrayOf("children")
        .withInitialValue(<initialValue>)
        .reduce(StringOperators.Concat.valueOf(ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.VALUE.getTarget())
            .concat(ArrayOperators.Reduce.Variable.THIS.getTarget())
        )
    ).build();

Replace the placeholders with your appropriate initial value and reduction expressions.

I have added in expression statement, now please post the complete code.

You are right, the absence of in caused spring data mongodb to not convert correctly.
